# Allow enter key inside Rad Telerik Multiline Textbox

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I want my Telerik Textbox to allow enter key inside it, it gets disabled when I use style.
My code:-

```
      <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtContent" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="300" Height="85px"
                            MaxLength="150" runat="server" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" Skin="Parcs" Style="white-space: normal;">
                        </telerik:RadTextBox>
```

> Style="white-space: normal;"
>   it is not allowing enter key inside textbox.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason `white-space: normal` styling doesn't work properly with RadTextBox's multiline mode (found in IE 11, not sure if exist in other browsers). Try using `white-space: pre !important;` instead:

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtContent" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="300" Height="85px"
                    MaxLength="150" runat="server" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" Skin="Parcs" 
                    Style="white-space: pre !important;">
</telerik:RadTextBox>
```

Or use `RadInput` CSS class which refers to `textarea` and add `pre` setting there:

```
.RadInput textarea {
    white-space: pre !important;
}
```

References:

[Enter key not work with radtextbox multiple line](https://www.telerik.com/forums/enter-key-not-work-with-radtextbox-multiple-line)

[RadTextBox multiline problem in IE 11](https://www.telerik.com/forums/radtextbox-multiline-ie11)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it is not working in chrome

Comment: Only on Chrome or all others? Check the console for CSS styling issue, probably Chrome has different way to enable Enter/Return key for RadTextBox.

Comment: We test it on IE11 and Chrome only